# Move Microsoft Dyamincs CRM 3.0 database from one SQL Server 2005 Server to another SQL Server 2005 Server

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-3

I found this documentation:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/917948

Does anyone have a better suggestion to accomplish this task?

Comment: What are you unhappy with in the MS doc? The description is kinda verbose, but it shouldn't be that bad.

Answer (score 0):

I used this document a couple of times to move from a SQL Server database to another, and if you follow each steps, it is pretty straightforward.

One of the steps is really important, the step #5 describe that some basic security information is given to SQLAccessGroup. If it's not done, the entire process does not work.

Also the agent jobs are rarely created automatically. So keep in mind that they should be backed up, and restored on the new server. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910044/. The CRM deployment should work without it, but will become slower as the database is growing.